# Rails LEFT OUTER JOIN with Subquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, subquery

I have a simple calendar application.

Models:

```
class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "sdate"
  has_many :items, foreign_key: :sdate
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :day, :foreign_key => :sdate
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
```

Requirements:
Fetch ALL rows of days within a certain date range.
Fetch associated rows of items with certain Calendar-IDs.

With SQL I could use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM days LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM items
  WHERE calendar_id IN (1, 4)
) AS items
ON days.sdate = items.sdate
WHERE days.sdate BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND '2015-03-31';
```

I have tried several ways in Rails but I couldn't find a solution.

How can I do this in Rails 4? Eager loading would be great.

Comment: those sound like 2 different requirements, are they ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just trying to figure this out and I don't know of any way to do it with pure Rails. But this will do what you want:

```
Day.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM items
    WHERE calendar_id IN (1, 4)
  ) AS items
  ON days.sdate = items.sdate
  WHERE days.sdate BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND '2015-03-31'");
```

I'm not using dates in the query in my code, so I'm not sure if you need the single quotes around the dates or not. But that is the syntax. I think Left joins are very handy, I wish Rails had an actual LEFT JOIN method.

Comment: Thank you Beartech! I will try it later today.

Comment: Sorry for being late! I will try it within the next two days.

Comment: The solution works. But unfortunately while accessing items
it produces a lot of additional database queries.

Comment: I see that with Rails a lot. Or at least it looks like a lot of queries, because Rails doesn't do a lot of eager loading. You are getting an ActiveRecord::Relation here, not just the results of a query. If you are concerned about DB queries, then the proper thing to do is create a database view using this query. Complex queries are the domain of the DB, and it is what the DB is designed to do. If you basically want a temporary table to see all of this query at once in one call, a DB view is the way to go. I'd appreciate it being marked as the correct answer unless a better one shows up.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting database views! Using a view could be a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
Day.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON days.sdate = items.sdate')
     .where('items.calendar_id IN (1, 4)')
     .where('days.sdate' => start_time..end_time)
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Thank you for your proposal!  
Unfortunately there is one problem:  
If there would be a day with just one item with calendar_id 3, this day
would be missing in the results.

Comment: Another problem: days without items are missing too.

Comment: Try running it in the console with `.to_sql` and tweaking it to produce the query you want.

Comment: Relation#to_sql returns an SQL statement. But I already have an SQL statement. So I don't understand why I should do this.